# Offset during line break in php

Tags: php, offset, line-breaks

I want to output a line in PHP at an offset. I am using

```
str_repeat(' ',5);
```

to create an offset but sometimes line is long and during line break; it starts at offset of 0. Any body has any ideas on how to control this?

Comment: ok, here it is {echo str_repeat(' ',5).$line;}

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are saying is that you want to indent your text by 5 characters, but sometimes the line is long and wraps around onto a 2nd line that is not indented.

The code below will work in basic scenarios by taking up to 50 characters at a time and then searching backwards for the last occurrence of the space character to determine the end of the last whole word.

In each iteration, the length of the line being 'echo'd is removed from the text so that it is not shown again.

```
$text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

while(strlen($line = substr($text,0,50)) > 0) {

    $line = substr($line, 0, strrpos($line,' '));

    echo str_repeat(' ',5). $line ."\n";
    $text = substr($text, strlen($line));   

}
```

The output is below. Hope it helps.

```
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
     adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
     incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
     enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
     ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
```

Comment: Yes, it can work but I am looking something that leaves no spaces on the right i.e. I want to replace 50 in your code with length of the line so it looks natural. Is there any way I can determine the length so it becomes more dynamic?

Comment: Where are you rendering the line? In web browsers?

Comment: Yes, for now, I am but later I will be printing it on the microsoft word.

Comment: IMHO, you would be better approaching this using HTML DIV tags and using CSS to fix the width with left padding to enforce the indent. Let Browsers and MS Word do the text wrapping for you, they will do a much better job than a few lines of PHP.